# IE download file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

Using the following lines of code I am able to download a file in the response of a Ajax call in Firefox, Chrome, Opera. However in IE the `href` attribute `download` is not supported. Therefore the below does not work in IE.

HTML:

```
 <div class="fRight" style="margin-left:5px; margin-rigth:5px" >
    <input type="button" value="Request File"  id = "chReqFileBtn"  onclick = "handleClick"/>
    <a href="#" id="challengeReqFileAnchor" style="visibility: hidden"></a>
 </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function handleClick()
{
    var code = $('#code').val();
    var quantity = $('#quantity').val();

    var req = $.ajax(
    {
        'type': 'POST',
        'url' : $apiBasePath+'config/challenge-file',
         contentType : 'application/json',
        'data': JSON.stringify({'code':code, 'quantity':quantity}),
        'success':function(response, status, xhr)
        {
            var code = xhr.getResponseHeader('Operation-Code');

            var anch = $('#challengeReqFileAnchor');
            anch.attr(
            {
                "download" : 'request.bin',
                "href" : "data:text/plain," + response       
            });
            anch.get(0).click();
        },
        'error': function(request,status,errorThrown) 
        {
           ......
        }
    });
    $pendingReqs.push(req);  
}
```

What options would I have to accomplish the same behavior in IE as well?

Comment: Why not let the server handle this? What is the purpose of the ajax call?

Comment: Sometimes a lower-tech approach is better - because it's not just IE that will have problems! Consider saving the AJAX result on the server (or simply making it a normal HTTP request in the first place) and having the server set appropriate `content-disposition` headers.

Comment: But if you absolutely want this in-browser: https://github.com/ChenWenBrian/FileSaver.js#examples

Comment: On the server side I set the specific headers to enforce donwload ,but since this is ajax it has no effect.I do it in ajax because I also need to execute extra code in the response .

Comment: my downloader script works in IE10+: http://danml.com/js/download.js it uses msSaveBlob for IE10 compat...

Comment: @steve why don't you create something like my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GuyT/r8oknrko/1/

Answer (score 28):

[Download attribute](https://caniuse.com/#feat=download) is NOT supported in IE and iOS Safari

[image]

### IE<10:

Command [SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801236(v=vs.85).aspx#saveas) using [execCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536419(v=vs.85).aspx) can do the trick, by making element's contents downloadable.

#### Cons:

- Problems in some versions of IE running on Win7 [I don't know if it's fixed [Here]](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929863)
- Need a DOM element to contain data

### IE>=10

Using [msSaveBlob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441122.aspx), it's a method that allows to save Blob or File by sending this headers:

```
Content-Length: <blob.size>
Content-Type: <blob.type>
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=<defaultName>
X-Download-Options: noopen
```

Check [Saving files locally using Blob and msSaveBlob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh779016(v=vs.85).aspx)

#### Cons:

- Need a to define a Blob

## Other browsers

If you don't want to implement all that by yourself, there is a nice library [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) to save generated files on client side. It supports Firefox, Chrome, Chrome for Android, IE 10+, Opera and Safari. For IE<10 there is a fork of the library that adds [saveTextAs](https://github.com/ChenWenBrian/FileSaver.js#examples) to save text files (.htm, .html, .txt)

## Cross browsers solution

A server side script that receives filename, data, meme type then send the file with the header `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=FILENAME`

Comment: Thanks for sharing the npm module - saved me hours :)

Answer (score 4):

I think this is related to the `anch.get(0).click();` not supported by all browser specially for `hidden` anchors, so you may try following code instead,

```
anch.get(0).show().focus().click().hide();
```

Answer (score 3):

IE does not support neither navigating to a data URI nor the `download` attribute.
You can use `navigator.msSaveBlob` to save file for IE 10+.
You can check `window.navigator.msSaveBlob`and write IE specific Code otherwise use existing code to save file.
You can check following link for more details:
[Saving files locally using Blob and msSaveBlob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779016(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

IE [does not support `download` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394871/download-attribute-on-a-tag-not-working-in-ie).

There's an *ugly* hack you can use however.

- Create an invisible `iframe`:

  ```
  <iframe id="dummy" style="display:none; visibility:hidden"></iframe>
  ```
- Write your data to the iframe's `document`:

  ```
  var ifd = document.getElementById('dummy').contentDocument;
  ifd.open('text/plain', 'replace');
  ifd.write('whatever you want to be in the file');
  ifd.close();
  ```
- Use [execCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536419(v=vs.85).aspx) to save the file (actually, to prompt the save as dialog):

  ```
  ifd.execCommand('SaveAs', true, 'request.bin');
  ```

Note that `execCommand` does not work in IE11. I know it is nearly impossible to detect the browser perfectly correctly. However you can try this as a backup routine if file saving fails in your code.

Answer (score 1):

My javascript version for download file from IE11 with BOM and charset for excel:

```
$.post('/cup-frontend/requestthewholelist',
    {ipAddressList: validIpAddressListAsString},   // add custom http variables
    function (returnedData) {                      // success return
        var BOM = "\uFEFF";                        // byte order mark for excel

        if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {                // ie block
            console.log("found msSaveBlob function - is't IE")
            var blobObject = new Blob([BOM + returnedData], {type: ' type: "text/csv; charset=utf-8"'});
            window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobObject, "cup_database.csv");
        }
        else {                                     // non-ie block
            console.log("not found msSaveBlob function - is't not IE")
            var a = window.document.createElement('a');
            a.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain; charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(BOM + returnedData));
            a.setAttribute('download', 'example.csv');
            a.click();
        }

    }).fail(function () {
    console.log('post error')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after doing hours of research I found some answer which really worked for me. Following approach worked for me.

```
if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // For IE
   return navigator.msSaveBlob(blobObj, fileName);
}
```

In below line

```
navigator.msSaveBlob(blobObj, fileName)
```

function **msSaveBlob** saves the file to the disk. Parameter **blobObj** is the object which needs to be saved with a given name in parameter **fileName**

For more information please visit following link:
[MDN Webdocs Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/msSaveBlob)