# Cross Browser file download on a button click compatible with Chrome and IE?

Tags: javascript, html, download

Images are hosted outside the server and are downloaded only to the user (client side).

I have tried the HTML5 download tag, but it does not work very well with IE.

```
<div style="width:800px; height:457px; background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/7fypLpI.jpg');"></div>
<a href="http://i.imgur.com/7fypLpI.jpg" download="http://i.imgur.com/7fypLpI.jpg">Download</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eLpc8d7u/

**How can I download the files for example with JavaScript for any browser?**

I've seen this other question: [IE download file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25121384/ie-download-file)

But I'm still confused to make a single script.

Comment: It's not exactly what you want but you can use part of my answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39589917/show-a-progress-bar-for-downloading-files-using-xhr2-ajax/39599878#39599878 (check the javascript code inside the `onreadystatechange` there)

Comment: Which IE version are you targeting, IE<10 or IE>=10 or both?

Comment: @Aruna IE>= 9 would be perfect, but with IE> = 10 it helps.

Comment: @ephramd Can you give a try with the below suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For cross browser download including IE < 10 and IE >= 10, you can use the below library which will do task easy for you.

http://danml.com/js/download.js

GitHub Location: https://github.com/rndme/download

Sample code snippet for your case:

```js
function downloadImage(event, url, fileName) {
  event.preventDefault();

  if(window.download && url) {   
     fileName = fileName || url.split('/').pop().split('?')[0];
     var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
          ajax.open( 'GET', url, true);
          ajax.responseType = 'blob';
          ajax.onload= function(e){ 
      download(e.target.response, fileName, 'application/octet-stream');
    };
          setTimeout(function(){ ajax.send();}, 0); // allows setting custom ajax headers using the return:
       return ajax;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://danml.com/js/download.js"></script>
<div style="width:800px; height:457px; background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/7fypLpI.jpg');"></div>
<a href="http://i.imgur.com/7fypLpI.jpg" onclick="downloadImage(event, 'http://i.imgur.com/7fypLpI.jpg')">Download with default file name</a><br/>
<a href="http://i.imgur.com/7fypLpI.jpg" onclick="downloadImage(event, 'http://i.imgur.com/7fypLpI.jpg', 'testImage.jpg')">Download with custom file name</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! Your example works fine here but on my server it returns the following error: 

"Xmlhttprequest cannot load no access-control-allow-origin header is present"

Is not it unsafe to enable that?

Comment: Is not compatible with FF

Comment: You can enable it only for the particular domain and not for all.

Comment: Let me check for FF

Comment: Okay, its a minor issue with `event` reference and fixed the same for FF now. Can you check now?

Comment: I have tried the following with the a tag and with only divs:

http://jsbin.com/fihozixozu/edit?html,css,js,output

Buttom 3 "ONLY DIV WITH PREVENT" works on IE and Chrome. But no code works for me in Firefox.

Comment: For 'A' tag, you should use `preventDefault`. The reason for this is, otherwise it will be redirected to the url specified in `href` attribute. For div, its not required. So out of the 4 links you have, 3 links working fine for me in all the browsers including Firefox. Check your browser console for any errors.

Comment: Thanks for replying again.
Have you tried this last code from jsbin.com or another site?
Since jsbin does not work for me in Firefox.
Debug reports missing CORS (Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

I'm researching on that.
In my server for example, no link works for that.
I have tried setting it from php:
<?php header ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>

But it does not seem to be enough.

Comment: Yes I tried from this link `http://jsbin.com/fihozixozu/edit?html,css,js,output` and no issues for me. Anyways it may depend on the browser version you have. Don't worry about `CORS` issue and its nothing to do with the above scripts. As long as you use this script in your own server, `CORS` issue won't occur. It will only occur, if you try one site from another site (cross origin) and your server blocks this request. Check the scripts locally instead of jsbin.

Comment: I have not finished understanding it.
As you say I have tried the code in local and works perfect in all 3 browsers (including Android) =) . However the same code on the server complains about this headers.

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://i.imgur.com/7fypLpI.jpg. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://myserver' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: Oh, I was using another picture link !!
This works on my server:
Http://i.imgur.com/7fypLpI.jpg
But this one does not:
Http://cdn1-www.comingsoon.net/assets/uploads/gallery/doctor-strange-1403135280/cf5nqhcxiae59i9-jpg-large.jpg

@Aruna I investigate about it. Thank you very much for all the help, it has been very useful!

Comment: You can try the image URL from your own server instead of a third party server which prevents CORS from specific server IP. You can google more about CORS to understand this.

Comment: Hi again! Do you use this library / script?
I've write on github because I can't rename a file. When I open the downloaded image it indicates erroneous headers .. https://github.com/rndme/download/issues/43

Comment: Let me check this today

Comment: @ephramd I have updated the answer above and please have a look for this. There are two links now one with default file name and other with custom file name.

Comment: thanks you again! Your response is spectacular! You deserve a 10/10 xD