# How to download a file in IE 11 using java script

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, apex

How do I download a file by clicking on a file in IE browser. I've written the code which works for all the browser like chrome and mozilla but not in IE. In IE if I click on the doc link to download, it goes to a blank page and shows nothing. Here is the code :

```
<apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header" >Document link Id</apex:facet>
    <div><a href="javascript:getAttachment( '{!doc.Document__r.Attachment_Id__c}','{!mapAttachments[doc.Document__r.Attachment_Id__c].Name}','{!mapAttachments[doc.Document__r.Attachment_Id__c].ContentType}')">{!doc.Document__r.name}</a></div>                                      
</apex:column>
```

Please help me out here

Comment: What IE version? Be more specific and please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Then edit that into your question. You seem to be using Visualforce, you should definitely note that in yout question. Also you should still provide a MCVE.

Comment: So what is `getAttachment ` ?

Comment: This is a well-known issue that has been covered in many questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25121384/870729