# Export pdf works on all browsers except internet explorer 11 in angular 5

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, export-to-pdf

I tried to test "Export PDF" angular on all web browsers (chrome, FireFox) it works correctly except on Internet Explorer 11

```
 //******************************************".html"******************************************//
     <button title="{{'purchase request'| translate}} PDF" mat-button class="header-button" 
    (click)="downloadPdf(prPurchaseRequest)">
     <mat-icon>cloud_download</mat-icon>{{'purchase request'|translate}} PDF
    </button>
//******************************************".ts"******************************************//
 /**
 *
 * Download PDF prPurchaseRequest
 */
downloadPdf(prPurchaseRequest) {
    this.spinnerstate = true;
    this.extraService.getCollection('api/pr-purchase-requests/generate_pdf/' + 
prPurchaseRequest.id).subscribe((response) => {
        setTimeout(() => { this.spinnerstate = false; }, 2000);
        const name = prPurchaseRequest.reference + '_purchase-request.pdf';
        const linkSource = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + response.data;
        const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');

        downloadLink.href = linkSource;
        downloadLink.download = name;
        downloadLink.click();
    });
}
```

//******************************Error Console in  internet explorer **********//
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually there's no error in console in IE. There're only two warnings and that's OK. PDF can't be downloaded when click the link because IE doesn't support [download attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Browser_compatibility).

You could [use Blob and msSaveBlob to save files in IE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/hh779016(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). `msSaveBlob` provides a **Save** button to the user and the user can click it to save the PDF file.

Sample usage in IE:

```
if(window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
    //IE11
    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blobData, fileName); 
}
else{
    //Other browsers
    //your function to download pdf
}
```

For more information, you could also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25121384/ie-download-file).

----------------------------------------------------------------Edit-----------------------------------------------------------

The `linkSource` you get is base64 string not blob data. You need to convert the base64 to blob then use the `msSaveBlob` function.

For the detailed information about converting base64 to blob, please refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript).

Comment: downloadPdf(prPurchaseRequest) {this.spinnerstate = true;this.extraService.getCollection('api/pr-purchase-requests/generate_pdf/' +prPurchaseRequest.id).subscribe((response) => {setTimeout(() => { this.spinnerstate = false; }, 2000);
const name = prPurchaseRequest.reference + '_purchase-request.pdf';
const linkSource = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + response.data;
if(window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
window.navigator.msSaveBlob(linkSource,name);  }
else{const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
downloadLink.href = linkSource;downloadLink.download =name;downloadLink.click();}});}

Comment: The problem still exists when I try this example

Answer (score 0):

Export works correctly but pdf is damaged :

```
downloadPdf(prPurchaseRequest) {
    this.spinnerstate = true;
    this.extraService.getCollection('api/pr-purchase-requests/generate_pdf/' + prPurchaseRequest.id).subscribe((response) => {
        setTimeout(() => { this.spinnerstate = false; }, 2000);

        const name = prPurchaseRequest.reference + '_purchase-request.pdf';
        const linkSource = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + response.data;

        if(window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {

              const blob = new Blob([linkSource], {type: "application/pdf;base64," });
              navigator.msSaveBlob(blob,name);
        }
        else{
            const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
            downloadLink.href = linkSource;
            downloadLink.download = name;
            downloadLink.click();
        }
    });
}
```

[image]