# Creating a download button for Internet Explorer in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, html

So like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394871/download-attribute-on-a-tag-not-working-in-ie/29278030?noredirect=1#comment50071192_29278030) IE doesn't support the `download` attribute. The second answer of that question offers a solution that uses an `iframe` with an HTTP header of: `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="some filename"` It suggests you attach that header using:

```
`header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="some filename"');`
```

I think this is PHP. Is there a way to do this in Django? Also the `.mp4` resource that they will be downloading when they click on the download button, is used on our website in other places. So not every request for that video should have this header attached. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is the file being served by a Django view, or is it a static file? If it's a static file, then the real question is "How do can I configure my server (e.g. Nginx or Apache) to do this".

Comment: I think these are static files, so I'll probably have to get with my server admin.