# How to make IE 11 support the download code?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I facing the problem on

```
<a href=" ..."  download></a>
```

this code not able support by IE 11,

```
<a href="try.zip">download?</a>
```

this code able support in IE 11, but I not allow to zip the csv because the csv will keep automatically updated, hence

any idea on how to make the download function in IE? thanks, sorry because I new to coding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download attribute on A tag not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394871/download-attribute-on-a-tag-not-working-in-ie)

Comment: I have try but still dunno hw to apply, can anyone give some simple example?

Answer (score -2):

using javascript:

```
   download(".....csv")
```