# Dowload button not working on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, spring, internet-explorer

I am working on thymeleaf and in my code i have a download button which triggers the javascript function.
The button is working well on chrome but not on Internet Explorer.

Javascript code:

```
function Download(containerid) {
        var fileName =  'tags.txt';
            var elHtml = document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML;
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            mimeType = 'text/html' || 'text/plain';
            link.setAttribute('download', 'ApiResponse.txt');
            link.setAttribute('href', 'data:' + mimeType + ';charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(elHtml));
            link.click(); 
        }
```

HTML from where it is being called:

```
<div class="tooltipp">
    <img onclick="Download('responseMessageEndpoint')"
    style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" th:src="@{css/download.jpg}" />
    <span class="tooltiptextt">Download</span>
</div>
```

From what i have googled, `download.createElement('a')` is not being supported by IE. But i am not able to fine a good workaround.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download attribute on A tag not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394871/download-attribute-on-a-tag-not-working-in-ie)

Comment: Did you mean `document.createElement('a')`?

Comment: IE does not support download on 'a' @RaphaelRafatpanah

Comment: `document.createElement('a')` is supported in IE. `Internet Explorer does not presently support the Download attribute on A tags` means something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IE browser not support [the Download attribute](https://caniuse.com/#feat=download). You could try to use msSaveOrOpenBlob method to download the file in IE browser.

Try to use the following code:

```
<script>
    function Download(containerid) {
        var returnedData = document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML;
        var filename = "hello.txt";
        var BOM = "\uFEFF"; 

        if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {                // ie block
            console.log("found msSaveBlob function - is't IE")
            var blobObject = new Blob([BOM + returnedData], { type: ' type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"' });
            window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobObject, "hello.txt");
        }
        else {                                     // non-ie block
            console.log("not found msSaveBlob function - is't not IE")
            var a = window.document.createElement('a');
            a.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain; charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(BOM + returnedData));
            a.setAttribute('download', 'hello.txt');
            a.click();
        }
    }
</script>
```