# How to download JSON file from response by Jquery & ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file, save

Similar question to this: [Download a file by jQuery.Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax).

There is my code:

```
    function saverequest(url, data) {
    var response = $.ajax({
        url: url,
        timeout: requestTimeout,
        global: false,
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function () {
            var blob = new Blob([response.data], {type : 'application/json'});
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.download = "export.json";
            link.click();
        }
    });

    return response;
}
```

[image: asd]

As i see in this picture, server-side responding with normal json data file.

But this code saving export.json file with "underfined" content inside.

There is a question: how to write data from response to blob object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you're using the `response` variable, which holds the jqXHR object returned from the `$.ajax()` call. This object does not have a `data` property, hence you see `undefined` in the output.

Given the pattern you're using, you should define an argument in the `success` handler function which receives the JSON data in the request, and then use that instead. Try this:

```js
function saverequest(url, data) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    timeout: requestTimeout,
    global: false,
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) { // note 'data' here
      var blob = new Blob([data], {
        type: 'application/json'
      });
      var link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.download = "export.json";
      link.click();
    }
  });
}
```

Also note that, depending on the browsers you need to support, you may need to append the `link` element to the DOM before the `click` event can be raised on it.

---

> Using this code I get `[object Object]` in the export.json file

This would be because the JSON holds an object, not an array as the `Blob()` constructor expects. To fix this provide the data in the `href` as plain text instead:

```
// change the AJAX request to retrieve the JSON as text (without deserialisation)
dataType: 'text'

// amend the href of the link to use text instead of a Blob
link.href = 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(data));
```

Comment: using this code i get "[object Object]" in export.json file

Comment: In which case it seems that the response is an object not an array as required by the `Blob` constructor. I've updated the answer to work around that

Comment: changed link.href as you said - same result, [object Object] in file

Comment: Try changing `dataType: 'json'` to `dataType: 'text'`

Comment: sorry for insistence, one more question, i need to add support for IE11, so how can i do it?

Comment: adding this to the DOM: `<a id="target" style="display: none"></a>`
and     
`var link = document.getElementById("target");`
doesn't work

Comment: The `download` attribute isn't supported in IE at all. There appears to be a couple of workarounds listed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44287509/519413), however their reliability seems patchy at best.